How to Reset the Value of an Angular Signal to Its Default Value?
I'm working on an Angular application that utilizes the @angular/core signal feature. I have a signal that initially holds a default value, but its value changes based on user actions throughout the application. How can I reset this signal to its default value?
Additional Information:
Angular version: v18

This is currently not supported by Angular Signals, but sounds like a reasonable feature to have. You can create an issue in their issue tracker: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues

I'd go with Naren solution, having signal keep their initial value would increase their memory footprint.

I’ve created an issue regarding this. please consider upvoting the issue to help bring attention to it. here is the link: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/58715

As far as I know there is no way to reset a signal back to an initial state, but we can declare the inital value in a property, then use the set method to reset the signal to it's initial value.
import { Component, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <input [value]="input()" (input)="setInput($event)"/>
    <button (click)="resetToDefaults()">reset</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  defaultInputVal = 'defaultValue';
  input = signal(this.defaultInputVal);

  setInput(event: any) {
    this.input.set(event?.target?.value);
  }

  resetToDefaults() {
    this.input.set(this.defaultInputVal);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
